# Configuring log4net for OWIN hosted WebApi service

Tags: c#, log4net, asp.net-web-api, owin, log4net-configuration

I have a WebApi hosted using OWIN on IIS. I do not want to refer log4net directly in my webapi, so I have created a logging library[log4net wrapper] that uses log4net. Now I am trying to configure the logging and I am not sure where I should use the XMLConfigurator to load the log4net configuration from webconfig.

Can anyone please let me know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should call the code that initialises your logging framework and configures log4net in your WebApi startup. The log4net config should be included in the WebApi project, ideally in a separate file so you can watch the file for runtime changes without restarting your application.